# teacher told me not to use static/dynamic vector pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

But what are those exactly? Is...

```cpp
vector<float> Vec;
Vec.push_back(2);
```

a pointer? If so, what other options can I use instead if I want to implement lists/vectors/arrays.

And for my own information: Are pointers a bad way to code or kinda outdated?

Comment: On the off chance that your teacher didn't tell you what a pointer is before asking you to implement something using a pointer, I figure a tutorial would explain well what a pointer is: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: *teacher told me not to use static/dynamic vector pointer* Can you elaborate on that?  I'm not sure what they are talking about with *static/dynamic vector pointer*

Comment: I was absent that day so I wasn't taught what a pointer is

Comment: Well it's exactly what he told me. Not to use "pointers for static/dynamic vectors/arrays/etc."

Comment: Did he mean static / dynamic allocation on pointers used as arrays ? Or did he means having arrays of element with "static" (fixed) size and dynamic size ?

Comment: If you have a problem understanding what your teacher said, why are you asking here? Why not ask your teacher?

Comment: @john Sorry but that logic is extremely dumb

Comment: @Quotenbanane Sorry I don't get it. Is your teacher unapproachable? It's your teachers job to help you with your programming problems.

Comment: It's none of your business why I'm asking here and not the teacher. If you really wanna know: The soonest I'll see him is next week. To contact him I'd have to dig up his email & ask him the exact same question. Since he's an elderly man he'd not reply immediately, maybe in a few hours or the next day. Plus there is the chance i'd get the reply "We did this in class, ask a friend".

Comment: TL, DR. If you have a problem with my question, tell me why or go on. Asking me WHY I'm asking this question is counterproductive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`std::vector<float>` class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a class and not a pointer.
I think your teacher wants to discourage you from using the c-style arrays:

```
float* array = new float[200];
```

This might be because using this you have to remember to delete them later:

```
delete[] array;
```

The `vector<float>` will handle this for you. Plus gives you nice methods like size, and dynamicaly resizes if you need more space.

There is a static variant: `std::array<float>`.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: okay. didn't looked at it this way.

Comment: How is that a bad question. It was at least good enough for generic_opto_guy to point me in the right direction.